# How to Configure Selectable weight to a product

Tags: magento2

[image]

Can anyone tell me how can we add selectable weight for the product like 50gms,1 kg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selectable in the way of defined beforehand? So options where you can choose from?

Weight:
- 50 grams
- 100 grams
- 500 grams
- 1 kilogram

Go to:

```
Stores -> Attributes -> Product
```

Add a new attribute, for example a text swatch, predefine some weight values, save the attribute and add it to your (default) attribute set, so you can select the attribute for each product. Note that the product has to be a configurable product so customers can select the desired weight on the storefront (front end).

Comment: tq.Its working...